# Wordpress Geo Location Search

Tags: wordpress, search, location, geo

OK, been looking for a plugin, but no luck. So I'm back at stack-

How can I add a Zipcode field to my wordpress posts that will enable me to offer a radius search to bring up only the posts within that radius? I've seen tons of geo related plugins, but none of them offer a search based on location.

Basically I want to list items/stores one per post and be able to bring them up in the search results.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to setup a zipcode database that has latitude/longitude for each zipcode. Then calculate distance between zips in mysql or php. Here's a site that implements this, apparently: [http://mondaybynoon.com/2010/02/22/store-locator-wordpress-pods/](http://mondaybynoon.com/2010/02/22/store-locator-wordpress-pods/) although it uses 'pods' which I'm unfamiliar with